# array of checkbox value checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I have this function, when I checked one or more checkbox the function load the value of the checked checkbox...but when I unchecked one or more check box the function show an empty array.

this is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
         var mycheck = new Array();
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#line-checkbox-1:checked").each(function () {
                mycheck.push($(this).val());//aggiungo value del checked
            });
             alert(mycheck)


        } else {
            var itemtoRemove = $(this);
            mycheck.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, mycheck), 1); //rimuovo il value del dechecked

            alert(mycheck);


        }

    });
```

This is HTML of the checkbox:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input tabindex="17" id="line-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" name="servizi" value="3">

 </div>
```

Comment: instread of $(this) use $(this).val() in else statement.

Comment: no also with .val() doesn't work

Comment: you have only one checkbox then why are you using loop. and id should be unique if multiple checkbox exists

Comment: No I have many checkboxes I have posted only one for example

Comment: just use this code no need to use if else condition as you are creating new array every time and use class instread of id http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Simple Script, this works for you:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () 
   {
        var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e,i) {
            return +e.value;
        });
        alert(arr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are using id to reference the checkboxes and since you are creating the array from scratch everytime user changes a checkbox. you should recheck the list everytime a checkbox is changed. That means you dont need that if.( if($(this).is(":checked") )

```
$('.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var mycheck = new Array();

    $(".checkboxes input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            mycheck.push($(this).attr("id") + ": is " + $(this).val()); //aggiungo value del checked
        }
    });
    alert(mycheck);
});
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4ut0aLd/1/) if i understand correctly what you are trying to do